From Functional Equation to Combinatorial Interpretation of Partitions
Define
$$T_1(x) = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} \frac{q^{\binom{m+1}{2}+mn+2\binom{n+1}{2}}x^{m+2n}}{(q;q)_m(q;q)_n}$$ and
$$T_2(x) = \sum_{m,n \ge 0} \frac{q^{\binom{m+1}{2}+mn+2\binom{n+1}{2}+n}x^{m+2n}}{(q;q)_m(q;q)_n}$$
Suppose, somehow, we conclude that $T_1(x)$ and $T_2(x)$ satisfies the following system of functional equations:
$T_1(x) = (x^2q^2+1)T_1(xq)+(xq+x^2q^3)T_2(xq)$
$T_2(x) = T_1(xq) + (xq+x^2q^3)T_2(xq)$
My aim is to extract (if possible) combinatorial interpretation of $T_1(x)$ just using the functional equations, i.e forgetting that we know what $T_1(x)$ is.
My Attempt for Combinatorial Interpretation:
I am assuming that $T_1(x) = \sum_\limits{m,n \ge 0} sp(m,n)q^nx^m$ where $sp(m,n)$ is the set of integer partitions of $n$ into exactly $m$ parts satisfying some conditions. In other words, we are assuming that $T_1(x)$ is a two-variable generating function for some set of integer partitions. We are using $q$ to keep track of the number which is partitioned , i.e the weight of the partition, and $x$ to keep track of the number of parts of the partition.
Then, the first equation tells us that if $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_m$ a partition enumerated by $T_1$, then

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1)$ is a partition enumerated by $T_1$ as well. In other words, replacing $x$ by $xq$ , combinatorially, means that add $1$ to each part.

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1) + (1) + (1) $ is a partition enumerated by $T_1$ as well. In other words, multiplying by $x^2q^2$ means that add two $1$s as a part to our partition.

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1) + (1)$ is a partition enumerated by $T_2$.

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1) + (2) + (1) $ is a partition enumerated by $T_2$.


Similarly, second equation can be translated as :
if $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_m$ a partition enumerated by $T_2$, then

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1)$ is a partition enumerated by $T_1$.

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1) + (1)$ is a partition enumerated by $T_2$.

$(\lambda_1 + 1) + (\lambda_2 + 1) + \cdots + (\lambda_m + 1) + (2) + (1)$ is a partition enumerated by $T_2$.


If we assume further that $sp(0,0) = 1$ i.e the empty partition is enumerated by $T_1$. Then, we can use the above rules to find the partitions which are enumerated by $T_1$, i.e start with the empty partition and using above rules construct a tree. Then, hopefully, we will see a pattern and guess partitions enumerated by $T_1$. Since, we know $T_1$ explicitly, then we try to prove that this is indeed the case either by algebraic manipulations on the generating function or via combinatorial reasoning on the explicit form of $T_1(x)$.
My Questions:

The rules I extracted from the functional equation is correct or not? I am confused whether these rules are in the if and only if format or if format or only if format:)

What if there is a coefficient like $2$ in the functional equation, say $T_1(x) = 2xqT_1(xq) + x^2q^3T_2(xq)$, how can we interpret this $2$?

If the coefficient is like $x^2q^3$ then there is a unique partition of $3$ into $2$ parts, namely $2+1$, what happens if we have a coefficient like $x^4q^8$, how can we interpret that?

Suppose we constructed the tree for $3$ - $4$ levels and there are some repetitions in tree. Can we conclude that we overcounting something?


PS: $(a;b)_k := (1-a)(1-ab) \cdots (1-ab^{k-1})$ if $k \ge 0$ and $(a;b)_0 := 1$.
Motivation: Maybe, I should add the motivating idea as well. Just looking at the explicit form of $T_1$, we may not see the partitions it is generating. We hope that the system of functional equation gives some information which are not at all obvious from $T_1$ itself.
Thank you very much in advance.
